# reinstall Ubuntu software center

Tags: installation, 10.10, software-center, uninstall

ciao a tutti,
ho disinstallato l'ubuntu software center perché mi dava problemi e, usando le vostre precedenti guide, ho provato a reinstallarlo, ma mi genera errori nel terminale e non lo installa. Cosa posso fare?

hello all,
I uninstalled the ubuntu software center because it gave me problems and, using your previous guides, I tried to reinstall it, but it generates errors in the terminal and will not install. What can I do?

Comment: we can't help you much If you don't mention those error messages.